# How to offline installe package and dependencies already downloaded with yumdownloader

Tags: centos, yum, r

I need to perform an installation (of R package) in a  server without internet access so i used yumdownloader to download the package and used --resolve to also download the dependencies, but when i try to install the package with:

```
yum install <path to .rpm file>/file.rpm
```

It does tries to install the  packge from the location, but yum tries to download the dependencies instead of using the ones downloaded , how do i specify yum to use only local files?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rpm`for that: `rpm -hiv *.rpm` in the directory where you downloaded the packages.
This will install all packages in the directory.